# Updating timestamp column by adding value from other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Scenario :

We have a table:

> GAME_PLAYED (id , start, game_duration )

In the UI We show the id, starttime, Finish time. ( Earlier Finish time was calculated by adding starttime + game duration)

(start and FINISH_TIME are of timestmap in postgres. game_ruation is of type : integer and it shows the seconds)

Now due to requirement change we are adding another column : FINISH_TIME.
**For the older data we want to update the existing table to populate values in FINISH_TIME**

So we were trying for this.

If I write staement like this :

```
Select start,  start+ INTERVAL 60 SECONDS as end 
from GAME_PLAYED as FINISH_TIME  
where id = 123
```

this works.

If I write

```
Select start, start + INTERVAL (
    SELECT game_duration 
    from GAME_PLAYED  
    where id = 123) AS FINISH_TIME 
from GAME_PLAYED  
where id = 123
```

**query doesn't work.** 
Can any one please tell me what is missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is data type of game_duration?

Comment: game_ruation is of type : integer and it shows the seconds.

Comment: What does "not work" mean exactly? Oh, and whoever thought of using the reserved word "begin" as a column namd should be fired.

Comment: So maybe that's the problem. According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html there's no defined behavior for timestamp + integer, and you're trying to convert integer to interval, which may not be supported from-the-box...

Comment: How about `Select start, (start + INTERVAL(game_duration)) AS FINISH_TIME from GAME_PLAYED  where id = 123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT
     start, 
     start + game_duration * INTERVAL '1 SECONDS' AS finish_time 
 FROM "GAME_PLAYED" WHERE id = 123;
```

BTW: There is no need to do subquery if you want to compute finish time for row with duration time from the same row.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :

I am trying something like this

```
Select start,  start+ INTERVAL '1 SECONDS'* duration 
from GAME_PLAYED as FINISH_TIME  
where id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Seconds are 1/(60*60*24) of a day.

```
Select start,  start +  game_duration / (60*60*24) as end 
from GAME_PLAYED as FINISH_TIME  
where id = 123
```